# Google featuring Stack Overflow answers now? (Chrome)

Tags: discussion, answers, google

[I just Googled a question](https://www.google.com/search?q=favicon+max+size), and in the same way that Google will feature its own quick answers to simple stuff like dates, calculations, translations, etc, it featured a Stack Overflow answer:

> [image: Screenshot]

What's this about? Google uses Wikipedia often as a featured source of information; is Stack Overflow on that level now? Am I missing something? This seems unusual.

Comment: Odd, when I do the same search that question comes up as the first result but it's displayed normally.

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome, are you? @PeterJ

Comment: No using Firefox, IE is the only other browser I have installed and that displays normally as well.

Comment: I get these kinds of featured answers in Chrome often. A chrome specific question, then. @PeterJ

Comment: It's worked for "size of int in java" for a few weeks or months now (in Safari and Firefox).

Comment: One hour later, this thread is now the top google hit for "google featured answer", but it doesn't have the featured answer thingie.  I'm confused.

Comment: @roippi Google seems to use the feature to display exact answers to a question, via the result. The algorithm apparently mistook the answer to the question above to be `32 x 32` - While flawed, it is an interesting idea. I have a feeling that should this become perfected, Stack Exchange will see millions of additional visitors each year.

Comment: this way, Google will at least avoid bumping too much into [summaries that are not a good fit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217913/165773). Pretty smart of 'em

Comment: Very interesting observation, and it should be quite exciting to see how that works out.

Answer (score 9):

### Google's OneBox

The algorithm is still clearly very flawed, [but have a look](http://searchengineland.com/google-search-onebox-answers-getting-detailed-182747); Google seems to be using OneBox to provide answers to more complex questions, based on public web resources.

I suspect that **Stack Exchange** will see a game-changing traffic increase, should this technology be perfected, due to the format.

Right now, clearly, the algorithm is having trouble providing reliable answers to questions. It makes sense, however, that Stack Exchange sites may be popping up more and more, if the OneBox continues development.

I would guess that in an attempt to improve the answer quality of the technology, Google may (or may have already) specifically target "Q&A" based sites to provide these answers.

Comment: For Wikipedia it has meant a decrease in visits but probably an increase in content reading.

Comment: @Elin You could say the same would be the case for SE on those grounds. However, I think that the majority of users will click the link for detail.