# Is Google doing something new with this site's data?

Tags: discussion, google

I just saw this in my Google result:

[image: Google search result page with box for Stack Overflow question]

You can even give feedback as to:

[image: Google feedback form for Stack Overflow question]

What is this and is it something new or has this been viewed before?

Comment: Did you click `Learn more` yet? Yes, this is a *experimental Google feature*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/3338405 it doesn't really describe the experiment though, it just says it is

Comment: Related: [Google "answering" my search with link to SE, but not showing the top answer(s)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233845)

Comment: @MartijnPieters too bad Google are not experimenting with meta answer as well :(

Comment: For those who don’t see the same result: Google sometimes runs experiments in the wild by transparently handling a small proportion of its users to servers running the experimental code. The collect the data, evaluate it and decide if the change improved search experience. Heard it in a documentary about Google, cannot find it now.

Comment: @Palec: `Heard it in a documentary about Google, cannot find it now` Did you try Googling it ;) ?

Comment: @MattBurland That was just a quick comment while leaving for pub. Now I managed to find Google’s paper [Overlapping Experiment Infrastructure: More, Better, Faster Experimentation](http://research.google.com/pubs/pub36500.html).

Comment: Google can do whatever she want and you will not put your nose in her business.

Comment: This should be a duplicate of some question that's on MSO, not MSE...

Comment: @Cupcake appears it is actually now that related questions works better: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254771/google-featuring-stack-overflow-answers-now-chrome?rq=1

Answer (score 48, accepted):

When you click that *Learn More* link in the feedback modal, you come to a page that states:

> Search is constantly evolving. In a typical year, **we experiment with tens of thousands of possible changes**. Every change is tested in an experiment where some users see the change and others don’t. By getting your feedback on our experiments, we learn which experiments are successful and should become part of Google Search for everyone.

It is a Google experiment; someone spotted this in early June already, when it was actually showing a less-than-ideal answer to a question; see [Google "answering" my search with link to SE, but not showing the top answer(s)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233845/google-answering-my-search-with-link-to-se-but-not-showing-the-top-answers)

Leave feedback and tell Google that the information shown is entirely useless; they should be using the existing [Schema.org microformat](http://schema.org/) markup that each Q&A page on Stack Overflow uses to mark up the question and answers with metadata. The specific microformat for [Q&A pages](http://schema.org/QAPage) was [inspired by Stack Overflow](http://www.w3.org/wiki/WebSchemas/QASchemaResearch), incidentally, and Google sponsors the Schema.org effort. Why they choose to show the `bottom-notice` and `question-stats` divs instead is a mystery to me.

Also see [Does Google special-case for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136397/does-google-special-case-for-stack-overflow)

Comment: I remember that Google used to show a question with 2 comments and 1 answer as having "3 answers"...but Google's fixed that now.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi seems they still got some work to do on the parsing, each bullet point has the first word of the new row on it :P

Comment: "Leave feedback and tell Google that the information shown is entirely useless" *starts a mob to send feedback*