# Google results have highlighted answers from Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, google

I was just curious about seeing this in Google results today:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I've not seen this before, so wondered if it was something new where [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11126756/57475) on [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11126659/57475), is highlighted in the same way definitions are in results. Has this been there long?

SO answer:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Below the answer is a *feedback* link, that allows for what looks like Google stats to be collected.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

After doing a few searches, it seems to only highlight things that have a definition of sorts as opposed to general code questions.

Comment: Looks like a license violation to me.  Is somebody going to click "make a legal removal request"?  Oh joy.

Comment: @Hans, license violation? Why? The highlighted excerpt provides attribution (although without a direct link to the author's profile, but given that several users can edit a question, that may not be feasible).

Comment: I don't see a link to the author's profile.  Did I miss it?

Comment: @Hans, yup, I edited my comment in that respect. I've always been wondering about this requirement -- what if 42 users have edited the question/answer, or if the post is community wiki? What would attributing to only the original author achieve then?

Comment: the actual blurb is made up of two separate answers on that question.

Comment: @Tanner, ah, that's right. It would be some kind of mash-up, then. Not sure if that can be generated automatically, or if an actual human being did the job. I don't know exactly what CC-BY-SA requires in that case, either.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I stumbled across that by accident. I have tried a few other searches on popular questions and haven't seen another instance yet, but I'm guessing there are plenty more.

Comment: This is known as the [Google Knowledge Graph](http://www.google.com/insidesearch/features/search/knowledge.html). I understand that new features appear all the time. A Google official came once to my university and said they have special agreements with data providers, so it might be reasonable to assume that the SO staff agreed about that.

Comment: @HansPassant: Let's hope noone did anything. They only show a short snippet and a link to the source, so it's fair use anyway.

Comment: I think this is actually great...

Comment: [Definitely](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233845) [not the](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268731) [first time](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254771/241211) this has been discovered. ;-)